# Object has no method push for heatmap

Tags: javascript, json, object, heatmap

Basically I am trying to do a Google heat map and map it onto my oneMap. I am using web service to execute a SQL statement and return JSON objects. Here is where I tried to set up the heat map:

```
function getHeatMap() {
var gradient = [
                        'rgba(185, 185, 203, 0)',
                        'rgba(145, 145, 192, 0)',
                        'rgba(65, 65, 207, 0)',
                        'rgba(30, 30, 229, 1)',
                        'rgba(0, 185, 255, 1)',
                        'rgba(0, 255, 215, 1)',
                        'rgba(0, 255, 15, 1)',
                        'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 255, 0, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 235, 0, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)'
]
var data = [];
var max = 0;
$.ajax({
    url: "index.aspx/getBusCommuter",
    type: "POST",
    data: "",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        var parsed = JSON.parse(data.d);
        $.each(parsed, function (i, jsondata) {
            var coordXicon = jsondata.BusStopX;
            var coordYicon = jsondata.BusStopY;
            var commuterAmt = jsondata.CommuterAmt;
            var point = new esri.geometry.Point({ "x": coordXicon, "y": coordYicon, "spatialReference": { "wkid": 3414 } });

            var count = commuterAmt;
            data.push({
                location: point,
                weight: count
            });

            if (count > max) {
                max = count;
            }

            var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
                data: data,
                radius: 30,
                opacity: 0.8,
                maxIntensity: max
            });

            heatmap.set('gradient', gradient);
            heatmap.setMap(map);
        });
    },
    error: function (request, state, errors) {
    }
});

}
```

I've checked the retrieve data part and it returns all the JSON objects I wanted. When I tried to draw the heatmap it throws me an error message `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'push'` at the data.push there. I wonder why is it so.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `data` is the argument in the success callback which is an object and it's hiding the `data` array variable you declared outside.

Comment: Sure thanks a lot. That solved the problem. But there is another error which is Uncaught InvalidValueError: setMap: not an instance of Map

Comment: @AnthonyChu Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Where did you define your map? This is probably just because there's no *map* available on that scope.